# Firebase Core causing crash on iOS11

Tags: ios, firebase, crash, ios11

Our app has been in production mode for 2 weeks now and we are seeing dozens of crashes, only on `iOS 11` devices. 
After fixing every little memory leaks, we still got 10% of users experiencing freezes & crashing randomly. 
We strongly suspect `Firebase Core`, used for tracking (Analytics), for crashing the users re-opens the app after being suspended in background.

In the crashing thread :

> libxpc.dylib    _xpc_connection_release_message + 396

In one of the other threads :

> libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply + 560

Crash details : http://crashes.to/s/10bfa061d0b

Has anyone experienced similar instability using `Firebase` on large scale audience app ?

EDIT :
Firebase version 4.13.0

Comment: Which version of the Firebase SDK are you using?

Comment: Actually 4.13.0

Comment: Logs seem to point to line 27 of UIStoryBoardExtensions.swift